# How to capture video stream in vlc?

Tags: video, console, video-streaming

I want to capture the video stream from the web-camera. I'm using vlc via console.

I used the following command:

```
cvlc /dev/video0
```

I've got the following exceptions...

```
VLC media player 2.0.5 Twoflower (revision 2.0.5-0-g1661b7d)
[0x8731db8] dummy interface: using the dummy interface module...
[0xb5000af0] filesystem access error: cannot open file /dev/video0 (Invalid argument)
[0xb5000af0] main access error: Reading from a file failed
[0xb5000af0] main access error: VLC cannot open file "/dev/video0". (Invalid argument)
[0xb4f005f0] main input error: open of `file:///dev/video0' failed
[0xb4f005f0] main input error: This source is not open
[0xb4f005f0] main input error: VLC could not open the MRL 'file:///dev/video0'. Look for more details in the log file.
```

Does anybody know how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by the following command:

```
vlc -I dummy v4l2:///dev/video0 --video-filter scene
```